# Full Screen Picture with Centered Text in a Wordpress Template File (php)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is my current page:
http://www.texaspaceauthority.org/travis-county/

I would like the title at the top ("Travis County") to be white text centered on a full width photo, such as that found at:
http://www.pelotonu.org/

I am editing from a template file, relevant code:

```
<div class="state-page-content container" id="state-page-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <!--// PAGE TITLE --> 
            <h1><? the_title()?></h1>
```

Is this possible to accomplish directly in the php? Or is there a better method?
I run a nonprofit pretty budget constrained, and so I have to do most of my coding myself.

In Sum, the questions:
-How do I add a full width photo?
-How do I then paste text over it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood your question but you can do something like:

```
<div class="state-page-content container" id="state-page-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <!--// PAGE TITLE --> 
            <h1 style="text-align:center;"><? echo get_the_title()?></h1>
```

Comment: OK, that works for the text, do you know how I would then overlay the text on top of a picture that is full length? Such as in the following site: http://www.pelotonu.org/ See how it has "Get a degree, stay debt-free" over a full width picture?

Comment: You need to create a Div with a background image and write the text hover it.

Comment: Are you aware of any instructions for this that you can quickly point to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The change should be made in your CSS file not the php. Im on mobile so i cant inspect it but its generally a simple text align / position change. You can do a relative position based on Your image container and use a "vw" text size to make it responsive